# GPU for pyswarms

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, gpu, particle-swarm

Is it possible to use gpu for pyswarms (in python)? My loss function calls the simulator so it takes alot of time and I wonder if it possible to parallelize the calculation for the particles of the swarm in each iteration?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Author of Pyswarms here

Currently we don't have that feature yet. It's in the roadmap, but we'd need more contributors and an active point-person to take charge in developing this feature. 
If anyone is interested, you can start the discussion by opening an Issue in https://github.com/ljvmiranda921/pyswarms